# Assign an identity key to non-identity key

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I have a table `table1`, the primary key is `Pkey`. It is an identity column. I have another table `table2` that has no primary key and identity column.

I want to insert the value of `Pkey` of `table1` into `id` column of `table2`.

```
obj2.id = obj1.Pkey;
```

I get an exception:

> *Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'table2'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.*

Thanks for hint. Does the system want to assign the identity property to id?

**UPDATE:**

Origninally table2 is empty, I created new record from entity framework.

```
BDetail obj2= iContext.DetailsRecords.Create();
obj2.id = obj1.Pkey;
iContext.BDetail.Add(obj2);
iContext.SaveChanges(); // exception here
```

Comment: It appears that your application tries to insert a NULL value. Is that a possiblity?

Comment: Can you share the table structure for both table1 and table2

Comment: Are you sure that obj1.Pkey is not null. What type is it, I presume int or something else?

Comment: If PKey is IDENTITY column it has to be NOT NULL! Maybe the Update statement itself has a problem where no return value tries to insert NULL into table2

Comment: Can you post full query that u have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that obj1 hasn't been created yet? Hence the NULL value from a primary key (which, if the row exists, can never be NULL).

Comment: It is entity framewok 4.0 method.

Comment: In the update code on row 2, if I understand correctly, shouldn't it say "obj2.id = obj1.Pkey;" as you stated in your original post? now it says "obj2 = obj1.Pkey;"

Comment: It is a typo. Never mind, the question is that if I change id as identity in sql server, then the exception vanishs in the air.